# UIDatePicker alignment inside static UITableView doesn't line up in storyboard vs simulator

Tags: ios, uitableview, uidatepicker

I'm trying to learn how to embed pickers into table views and am starting off nice and simply with a static tableview where I've inserted a UIDatePicker within it.

Unfortunately I'm seeing odd behaviour with how the UIDatePicker aligns within the cell. If I line everything up nice and centred within the storyboard then when i run in the simulator i find the picker displays lower than centred and so looks messy. In the end by eye I've had to add padding to the cell beneath the picker in the storyboard to get it looking reasonable within the simulator when running. As shown in the following images.

Anyone any ideas why the storyboard layout isn't being honoured, or whether there's something I can change which would make them behave themselves better?

Apologies for the image resolution size.

**layout of picker and cell in the storyboard**

[image: layout of picker and cell in the storyboard]

**outline of my tableview in the storyboard**

[image: outline of my tableview in the storyboard]

**picker and cell shown in the simulator**

[image: picker and cell shown in the simulator]

Comment: are any of the delta values set in your storyboard, for the datePicker ?

Comment: I couldn't see anything odd in the delta values (on the ruler tab right?) - I think i've fixed it now.. i'll write a proper answer for people's future reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I eventually fixed this... i tried using some auto constraints having snapped the picker to the centre of the cell, sadly this didn't seem to help.

I then cleared the constraints and used the align button to add constraints for horizontal and vertical center in container. Added these constraints and now the picker is behaving consistently between the storyboard and the simulator.

Not sure why when adding it centred using the blue guidelines it didn't default to this sort of behaviour without the constraints but now I know.

Thanks to anyone who took the time to read my question.